# JPA merge with @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false) doesn't return the actual column value

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Simply put, i have a column in the database that is set like that:

```
create table if not exists thing(
    id bigint primary key,
    ...,
    test int default 5
);
```

And an Entity like that:

```
@Entity
public class Thing {

    private long id;
    ...
    private int test;
    ...

    @Id public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }

    public void setTest(int test) { this.test = test; }

    @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
    public int getTest() {
        return test;
    }
```

When i merge a new entity like that:

```
Thing thing = new Thing ();
thing.setId(123);
Thing managed = em.merge(thing);
```

`managed` won't have the `test` field synched with the database. It will show `0`. How can i force all JPA to update what is essentially an immutable field that is set by the DB?

The purpose of this is to have a date created field. But also other scenarios like DB fields that are set by triggers...

Comment: Why not call `em.refresh`? `em.merge` is nothing to do with getting values from the database

Comment: @BillyFrost i guess i will do it that that way. I just though it could be done in one single operation.

Answer (score 0):

As Billy Frost mentioned - you have to refresh the entity from the database.

But before calling refresh you have to force Hibernate to execute the SQL statements.

```
Thing thing = new Thing ();
thing.setId(123);
Thing managed = em.merge(thing);

em.flush(); // executes SQL statements
em.refresh(managed ); // gets the managed thing from the database
```